# インストールしたgemがPATHに追加されない

Tags: rbenv

私はCentOS上にrbenvでrubyをインストールしました。
そしてbundleというgemをインストールしました。
しかしbundleがPATHに追加されていません。

実際に入力したコマンドで説明させていただきます。

```
gem install bundle
rbenv rehash
bundle
```

この時に以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
bash: bundle: command not found
```

しかしbundleは`/root/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/`にインストールされています。

またshimsは以下のようになっています。

```
ls ~/.rbenv/shims/
erb  gem  irb  rake  rdoc  ri  ruby
```

なぜこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？ご回答よろしくお願いします。

## 補足説明等

コメントで指摘いただいた、不足の情報をここで補足させていただきます。

環境はDocker上のCentOSに対して、Ansibleを使い環境を構築しています。

whoamiの実行結果です。

```
$whoami
root
```

gem environmentの実行結果です。

```
$gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
     - /root/.rbenv/libexec
     - /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /root/.rbenv/shims
     - /root/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /root/bin
```

bash_profileの内容です。

```
$cat ~/.bash_profile

# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: 手元の CentOS on Docker において手動で (1) rbenv をインストール (2) ruby-build をインストール (3) `rbenv install 2.5.1` && `rbenv global 2.5.1` (4) `gem install bundle` && `rbenv rehash` としたところ、`bundle` が正常にインストールできてしまいました。`gem environment` の結果は一致しました。ただし `type bundle` は `bundle is hashed (/root/.rbenv/shims/bundle)` であり、ディレクトリ `.gem/ruby` が存在しなかったので、何か違いそうです。`~/.gemrc` が存在していて、それによって設定が上書きされていたりしませんでしょうか？　たとえば `install: "--user"` があると `~/.gem` 以下に[ダウンロードされます](https://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install)。

Comment: 御返答ありがとうございます。調べて見たところgemrcは存在しませんでした。原因はわからないですが、PATHに追加する方法で解決しようと思います。

Comment: Ansible に詳しくないのですが、[このドキュメント](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/gem_module.html)を見ると `user_install` のデフォルト値が yes になっているように見えます。ここを no に設定すると追加の設定は不要かもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 原因

`~/.gemrc` における `install: "--user"` という設定や Ansible の[設定](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/gem_module.html)など、何らかの理由により gem のインストール先がデフォルトではなくユーザーが設定した場所になっています。このようにしてインストールされた gem は通常 `~/.gem/ruby/<バージョン>/bin` にインストールされますが、何も設定していないとここへの PATH は通っていないのでコマンドが見つからないというエラーが出ます。

尚デフォルトのままインストールされていたとすると、gem は `~/.rbenv/versions/<バージョン>/bin` にインストールされ、`type bundle` の結果が

```
bundle is hashed (~/.rbenv/shims/bundle)
```

のようになるはずです。

#### 対策

いくつか方法があります。

- ユーザー設定の場所にインストールする意味が無いのであれば、設定を変えて再インストールする。
- ユーザー設定のインストール先を PATH に追加する。たとえば Ruby の公式 FAQ "[I INSTALLED GEMS WITH `--user-install` AND THEIR COMMANDS ARE NOT AVAILABLE"](https://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install) には例として以下のスクリプトを `~/.bashrc` に追記すると良い、と書かれています。

  ```sh
  if which ruby >/dev/null && which gem >/dev/null; then
      PATH="$(ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"
  fi
  ```

Comment: 御返答ありがとうございます。こちらのスクリプトでPATHに追加する事が出来ました。ありがとうございます。